# SQL schema for modelling of group fields

Tags: sql-server, database-schema

I have been asked to make some adjustments to an existing SQL database however am having trouble working out how to model the following scenario:

At the present time, an order item can or cannot be associated with a Pallet. At the present time this is just an integer field on the database table. If some of the fields on that order item are updated, this needs to be reflected in all other items that share the same PalletID. I have been asked to do this synchronisation through code but it feels bad and is going to be prone to easily getting out of sync.

I considered making a new table tblPallet which would contain the shared fields however in the case that an order item does not have a pallet, the order item would still need to store its own copy of those details:

### Order Item

ID,
Description,
PalletID,
CurrentStage,
Location,

### Pallet

ID,
CurrentStage,
Location

Has anyone get any alternative ideas for modelling this?

Comment: I still don't understand the problem

Comment: Sorry, its quite hard to explain the problem...
Consider a box as the order item. In some cases, this box may be small and put onto a bigger pallet with other items. As such, the Location of that Order Item box is where its Pallet is and all other items on that pallet will be at the same location.

Comment: Another order item may or may not be put onto a pallet but it would still need to have a location and stage. It could even be put onto a pallet later on down the process in which case it would then have the location of the parent pallet

Comment: Why not allow an order item to be the only order item in a pallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If before being on a pallet, one or more items can share the same `CurrentStage` and `Location` I would use following solution (in this case `CurrentStage` and `Location` columns at item level and `CurrentStage` and `Location` at pallet level are xor; if `OrderItemGroup.CurrentStage` and `OrderItemGroup.Location` are filled then `OrderItemGroup.PalletID` should be NULL or if `OrderItemGroup.PalletID` is filled then `OrderItemGroup.CurrentStage` and `OrderItemGroup.Location` should be NULL):

```
OrderItem(
    ID - PK, 
    OrderID - FK, 
    ... other columns except PalletID, CurrentStage, Location ...
)

OrderItemGroup(
    ID - PK, 
    OrderItemID - FK, 
    CurrentStage - allows NULLs, 
    Location - allows NULLs, 
    PalletID - FK - it allows NULLs, 
    CHECK(CurrentStage IS NOT NULL AND Location IS NOT NULL AND PalletID IS NULL 
    OR CurrentStage IS NULL AND Location IS NULL AND PalletID IS NOT NULL)
    -- {CurrentStage, Location} xor {PalletID}
)

Pallet(
    ID - PK, 
    CurrentStage - NOT NULL, 
    Location - NOT NULL
)
```

2) But if before being on a pallet, items from the same order have (most of the times) different `CurrentStage` and `Location` I would use following solution (in this case `CurrentStage` and `Location` columns at item level and `CurrentStage` and `Location` at pallet level are xor):

```
OrderItem(
    ID - PK, 
    OrderID - FK, 
    CurrentStage - allows NULLs, 
    Location - allows NULLs, 
    PalletID - FK - it allows NULLs, 
    CHECK(CurrentStage IS NOT NULL AND Location IS NOT NULL AND PalletID IS NULL 
    OR CurrentStage IS NULL AND Location IS NULL AND PalletID IS NOT NULL)
    -- {CurrentStage, Location} xor {PalletID}
)

Pallet(
    ID - PK, 
    CurrentStage - NOT NULL, 
    Location - NOT NULL
)
```

**2.1)** If you have to store location history then I would use following approach (it's not the only solution but - in my opinion - it's the simplest):

```
OrderItem(
    ID - PK, 
    OrderID - FK, 
    -- other columns except CurrentStage, Location and PalletID
)

Pallet(
    ID - PK, 
    CurrentStage - NOT NULL, 
    Location - NOT NULL
)

OrderItemLocationHistory (
    ID - PK,
    OrderItemID - FK,
    IsCurrentLocation BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT (1),
    CurrentStage - allows NULLs, 
    Location - allows NULLs, 
    PalletID - FK - it allows NULLs, 
    CHECK(CurrentStage IS NOT NULL AND Location IS NOT NULL AND PalletID IS NULL 
    OR CurrentStage IS NULL AND Location IS NULL AND PalletID IS NOT NULL)
    -- {CurrentStage, Location} xor {PalletID}
)

    -- SQL2008+ following unique filtered index guarantee there is only only one row with IsCurrentLocation = 1 for every OrderItemID
    SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
    GO
    /*
    See section [Required SET Options for Filtered Indexes]:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx
    */
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IXF_OrderItemLocationHistory_OrderItemID_IsCurrentLocation1
    ON dbo.OrderItemLocationHistory (OrderItemID)
    WHERE IsCurrentLocation = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed comments.
I think option 2 will work well for me. The simpliest solution would have been to give every item a pallet as suggested by another user however this could get a little messy if an order items pallet changes and would thus leave a redundant pallet record in the database. I guess this could still happen here to ...

Comment: @Ross: it depends if you want to store the full history of pallets of every item or if you want/need to store only the last / current pallet for every item.

Comment: I think ideally I would want to store the full history so that there is an audit record of how an orderitem has moved around